# How to toggle the main drawer of a drawer panel using a toolbar button

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, material-design, paper-elements, core-elements

I am attempting to listen to a button click on the a toolbar that toggles the main drawer of a drawer_panel when the button is clicked, but without much success.

The code is shown below - the code in the method void menu_icon_handler() is incorrect.

```dart
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <link rel="import" href="../../../packages/polymer/polymer.html">
    <link rel="import" href="../../../packages/core_elements/core_drawer_panel.html">
    <link rel="import" href="../../../packages/core_elements/core_icon_button.html">
    <link rel="import" href="../../../packages/core_elements/core_toolbar.html">
    <link rel="import" href="../../../packages/paper_elements/roboto.html">
    <link rel="import" href="../../../packages/core_elements/core_toolbar.html">
    <link rel="import" href="../../../packages/paper_elements/paper_icon_button.html">
    <link rel="import" href="./reg/registrant-view.html">
    <link rel="import" href="./reg/patient-view.html">
    <link rel="import" href="drawer-form.html">

    <polymer-element name="main-form">

      <template>
        <core-drawer-panel id="core_drawer_panel">
          <section id="drawer" drawer>
            <drawer-form on-new-patient-event='{{newPatientHandler}}'></drawer-form>
          </section>

          <section id="main" main>
            <core-toolbar id="core_toolbar">
              <paper-icon-button
                icon="menu"
                id='menu_icon'
                on-click='{{menu_icon_handler}}'></paper-icon-button>
              <div id="div" flex>Toolbar</div>
            </core-toolbar>

            <section id='new-patient'>

            </section>

          </section>
        </core-drawer-panel>

      </template>

      <script type="application/dart">

        import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
        import 'dart:html';

        import 'package:core_elements/core_drawer_panel.dart';

        @CustomTag( 'main-form' )
        class MainForm extends PolymerElement
        {
          CoreDrawerPanel drawerPanel;

          MainForm.created() : super.created();

          void toggleDrawer()
          {
            bool state = drawerPanel.narrow;
          }

          void menu_icon_handler()
          {
            bool state =  drawerPanel.narrow;

            print ( state );
          }

          @override
          void attached()
          {
             super.attached();

             drawerPanel = $['drawerPanel']  as CoreDrawerPanel;
          }
        }
      </script>
    </polymer-element>
```

When the toolbar button is clicked, I get the following stacktrace

Exception: The null object does not have a getter 'narrow'.

```dart
NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'narrow'
Receiver: null
```

I see the null, looking at the docs 'narrow' is an attribute of CoreDrawerPanel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You look the element up with

```dart
drawerPanel = $['drawerPanel']  as CoreDrawerPanel;
```

but your HTML doesn't contain an element with id `drawerPanel`, but you have an element with id `core_drawer_panel`

changing the id in this line should solve the problem

```dart
drawerPanel = $['core_drawer_panel']  as CoreDrawerPanel;
```

Comment: Thanks. Carelessness on my part.